# C read a file, line by line to vector

Tags: c, file, vector

I just started coding in C.
I have implemented a vector that seems to be working when i append strings to it,
but as soon as i read from the file i seem to get the last string again and again.
From what i can see it seems like it uses the same address and therfore i get the same line again and again.

But i can't seem to find a solution to the problem, hope you can help.

this is my vector structure:

```
void vector_init(Vector *vector){
    vector -> size = 0;
    vector -> capacity = 20;
    vector -> data = malloc(sizeof(void *) * vector -> capacity);
```

}

and appending to vector:

```
void vector_push(Vector *vector, void *value){
    vector_double_capacity(vector);
    vector -> data[vector -> size ++] = value;
}
```

and here is what i do in my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Vector someVector;
    vector_init(&someVector);

    FILE *fp;
    void *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1){
        vector_push(&someVector, line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n");

    vector_push(&someVector, "blah");
    vector_push(&someVector, "test");
    vector_push(&someVector, "some random txt");
    vector_push(&someVector, "yollo");
    vector_push(&someVector, "something");

    for (int i = 0; i < someVector.size; i++)
        printf("\nvalue is : %s", (char *) vector_get_element(&someVector, i));

    return 0;
}
```

My get_element function:

```
void *vector_get_element(const Vector *vector, size_t index){
    if (index >= vector -> size || index < 0){
        printf ("Index %d out of bounds", (int) index);
    }
    return vector -> data[index];
}
```

here is my output:

```
value is : terminal
value is : terminal
value is : terminal
value is : terminal
value is : blah
value is : test
value is : some random txt
value is : yollo
value is : something
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If you double the size of your vector every time you add one element, you're going to run out of memory really fast.

Comment: Can you post the `getline` function? I believe that's where the problem is.

Comment: @xiaofeng.li [`getline` is a POSIX-standard function.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)

Comment: added my get_element function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the data you add to your vector.

```
void vector_push(Vector *vector, void *value, size_t bytes){
    vector_double_capacity(vector);
    void *copy = malloc(bytes);
    memcpy(copy, value, bytes);
    vector -> data[vector -> size ++] = copy;
}
```

You'd have to call that with something like

```
vector_push(&someVector, line, 1 + strlen( line ) );
```

to preserve your vector's apparent purpose of holding a pointer to any type of data and not just `NUL`-terminated strings.  You may also want to add a `size` field to your structure so you know how much data is pointed to.

Comment: The standard way vectors are implemented is similar, but (1) your "double_capacity()" function should simply return if the vector isn't full, otherwise it reallocates it bigger, copies the values, and de-allocates the old one; and (2) increasing the capacity by 150% is a better speed/memory waste tradeoff.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I understand that.  I deliberately tried to keep this answer as close to the code in the original question as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple way around this.

```
while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1){
   vector_push(&someVector, line);
}

line = NULL;
```

by setting line to NULL